# Dark UI in sublime text 3

Tags: user-interface, themes, sublimetext3

I've installed the SETI_UI theme through Package Control.

I can't work out how to get the dark UI, like on the screenshot here:
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Seti_UI

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed Seti_UI through package control, you should be able to change your color scheme and theme by doing the following:

---

1. Open up your Preferences/Settings - User/
2. The "color_scheme" and "theme" options in the file should be set like this:

---

```
{
  "color_scheme": "Packages/Seti_UI/Scheme/Seti.tmTheme",
  "theme": "Seti.sublime-theme",
}
```

There may be other options in that file, but make sure those two are set correctly.

Comment: got it... I'd made the change the user setting file, but it wasn't updating the UI... randomly fixed now...weeird!

Comment: Glad its working. I would recommend you look into [Schemr](https://github.com/benweier/Schemr) and [Themr](https://github.com/benweier/Themr). They are packages that make it extremely easy to switch your color scheme and theme respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you don't know how to change your theme? 
After you install the package, it will open a new window with `example code`. copy it, after that go to `Preferences > Settings User` and after that paste code from before.
If nothing happened, you can try to change it from here : `Preferences > Color Schemes >`